# Collapsing priority in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have four wells in two rows. Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 well">
            <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 well">
            <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 well">
            <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 well">
            <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the bootply: http://bootply.com/100389

Now, it is visible to us as:

```
|  1  | 3 |
|-----|---|
|  2  | 4 |
```

In mobile devices, the order is 1 then 3 then 2 and then 4.

But, what I want is that the ordering should be 1,2,3 and then 4. How do I do that?

Comment: Reordering elements is not something CSS is equipped to do.

Comment: True that, but there must be some way to do it. Using `@media` would be a very obvious way to do it, but I need something that doesn't involve js, but simple manipulation of css

Comment: Do you want to keep the column layout on mobile, or simply want them to stack on top of each other?

Comment: @rae1n didn't get it. What's the difference?

Comment: I meant, on a mobile layout you want the `3-4` column to stay on the side of `1-2` as another column, or do you want `3-4` column to stack under `1-2`? In the first case, when you go mobile you get to keep the same layout you have now on desktop; in the second case you only see the first column and the second column is pushed down.

Comment: @rae1n I want the second case. But, how can you achieve the first case?

Comment: @Ranveer if you want to keep the same layout on mobile, just use `col-xs-X` instead of `col-md-X`.

Comment: Well, the code in my answer achieves the first case. But I agree I understand the question wrong.

Comment: I wanted the second case, but extra knowledge doesn't hurt. Thanks!

Comment: @rae1n mention that in your answer. Else it might be misleading for future referrers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="well"><h1>1</h1></div>
            <div class="well"><h1>2</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="well"><h1>3</h1></div>
            <div class="well"><h1>4</h1></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. Clearly I spoke too soon.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what was required.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to keep the same layout, with the columns side by side rather than with the columns on top of each other, try adding `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*`  to each column `div`,

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 well">
            <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 well">
            <h1>3</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 well">
            <h1>2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 well">
            <h1>4</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are not changing the column widths based on the view-port (i.e. `col-xs-6 col-sm-4`), then you only need to use the `col-xs-X`(the smallest view-port class, where you actually want the columns to break). `col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4` is just redundant...